# Index of Position of Values from B in A

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a little bit of a tricky problem here...

Given two arrays A and B

```
A = np.array([8, 5, 3, 7])
B = np.array([5, 5, 7, 8, 3, 3, 3])
```

I would like to replace the values in B with the *index of that value* in A. In this example case, that would look like:

```
[1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```

For the problem I'm working on, A and B contain the same set of values and all of the entries in A are unique.

The simple way to solve this is to use something like:

```
for idx in range(len(A)):
    ind = np.where(B == A[idx])[0]
    B_new[ind] = A[idx]
```

But the B array I'm working with contains almost a million elements and using a for loop gets super slow. There must be a way to vectorize this, but I can't figure it out. The closest I've come is to do something like

```
np.intersect1d(A, B, return_indices=True)
```

But this only gives me the *first* occurrence of each element of A in B. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The solution of @mozway is good for small array but not for big ones as it runs in `O(n**2)` time (ie. quadratic time, see [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for more information). Here is a much better solution for big array running in `O(n log n)` time (ie. quasi-linear) based on a fast **binary search**:

```py
unique_values, index = np.unique(A, return_index=True)
result = index[np.searchsorted(unique_values, B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy broadcasting:

```
np.where(B[:, None]==A)[1]
```

*NB. the values in `A` must be unique*

Output:

```
array([1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Though cant tell exactly what the complexity of this is, I belive it will perform quite well:

```
A.argsort()[np.unique(B, return_inverse = True)[1]]
array([1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Interesting. The complexity is roughly `O(n log n)` like my solution, so it should be significantly faster than the one of mozway for big arrays, but it is a bit slower than mine (especially if `A` is much smaller than B) since `argsort` is pretty expensive (and `np.unique` on a big B is more expensive than a `searchsorted`).